# Ttrying to load a table using react-bootstrap-table

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

Trying to edit the table cells using react-bootstrap-table, I am able edit successfully, but when I click on other components in the page the edited content has been restored by original value.

```
export default class PredictResult extends React.Component<IPredictResultProps, IPredictResultState>
render()(
<my table code >)
```

each time I click or hover  on other component, the whole page is rendering the whole component in the page and values in the table are restored.

Answer (score 0):

when you click somewhere component render again so you must change the state in "onChange" method (change the record that you pass to table with setState method)

> **it's just an example**

```ts
const Firstlist = [{ id: 1, label: 'lable1' }, { id: 2, label: 'lable2' }, { id: 3, label: 'lable3' }]
const App = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState(Firstlist);
const onChaned=(value,item)=>{
  item.label=value;
  setList([...list]);
  
}
  return (
    <Table>
      <thead>
        <th>
          <td>Id</td>
          <td>Lable</td>
        </th>
        <tbody>
          {list.map(item => <tr key={item.id}>
            <td>{item.id}</td>
            <td><Input value={item.label} type='text'
              onChange={({ target }) => onChaned(target.value,item)} >{item.label}</Input></td>
          </tr>)}
        </tbody>
      </thead>
    </Table>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: could you pls explain wiht examples..